What could be the cause of my SPM CAT12 preprocessing errors?
I'm relatively new to SPM and related tools, and run into some issues running CAT12 segmentation in batches.
Individual subjects through the GUI works fine, but when we submit a script to process several subjects, several issues arise:

issue 1:
MATLAB:sizeDimensionsMustMatch
Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Which arrays is it referring to here? How can I check and correct?

issue 2:
MATLAB:UndefinedFunction
Unrecognized function or variable "VI".

Which variable are they referring to?

issue 3:
Error reading header file

For some of these issues, some output is still produced, but we struggle to distinguish when a subject has run succesfully. For issue 3, the complete output is not produced.
We run a bash submission script on a slurm cluster that calls a matlab script for the CAT12 segmentation:
Bash script:
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=segmentations_ahead
#SBATCH --mem=4G
#SBATCH --partition=luna-cpu-short
#SBATCH --qos=anw-cpu
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --time=00-03:00:00
#SBATCH --nice=2000
#SBATCH --array=1-3%3
#SBATCH --output=slurm-%A.%a.out

# Load Matlab module
module load matlab/R2021b
export MATLABPATH=path/to/cat12

inputdir=path/to/input

cd ${inputdir}

ls -d sub-*/ | sed 's:/.*::' > subjects.txt

subjects=${inputdir}/subjects.txt
subj=$(sed -n "${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}p" ${subjects})
# random delay
duration=$((RANDOM % 20 + 2))
echo -e "${YELLOW}INITIALIZING...(wait a sec)${NC}"
echo
sleep ${duration}


matlab -nodisplay -batch "AHEAD_segmentation $inputdir $subj"

Matlab script:
function AHEAD_segmentation(inputdir,subj)

% Define paths
addpath('path/to/spm12');

% Get a list of all subject directories
%subjects = dir(fullfile(input_dir, 'sub-*'));

% Loop over each subject
%for i = 1:length(subjects)
    % Define the subject's anat directory within ses-1

    subj_dir = fullfile(inputdir, subj, 'ses-1', 'anat');
 %   t1_image_gz = fullfile(subj_dir, [subj '_ses-1_acq-wb_mod-t1w_orient-std_brain.nii.gz']);
      t1_image = fullfile(subj_dir, [subj '_ses-1_acq-wb_mod-t1w_orient-std_brain.nii']);

      % Show file path
    disp(['Checking: ', t1_image]);

    % Check if file exists
    if exist(t1_image, 'file') ~= 2
        fprintf('Warning: File %s not found!\n', t1_image);
        error('no T1 file'); % Skip to next subject if T1 is missing
    end

    % Check if the gzipped T1 image exists
    if ~isfile(t1_image)
        fprintf('T1 image not found for subject %s\n', subj);
    end

    % Print status
    fprintf('Processing subject %s\n', subj);

    % Set up CAT12 batch job for segmentation
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.data = {t1_image};
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.nproc = 1;          
    %matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.opts.tpm = {fullfile(spm('path/to/spm12'), 'tpm', 'TPM.nii')}; % Path to SPM's TPM file
    
    spm_dir = spm('dir');  

    % Path to TPM file
    tpm_file = fullfile(spm_dir, 'tpm', 'TPM.nii');

    % Check if the file exists
    if ~exist(tpm_file, 'file')
        error('TPM file not found: %s', tpm_file);
    end

    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.opts.tpm = {tpm_file};

    % select modality for SPM
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.opts.modality = 'T1';  

    % Output options for volume-based analysis
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.surface = 1; % Disable surface-based outputs
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.GM.native = 1;   % Output native gray matter volume
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.WM.native = 1;   % Output native white matter volume
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.CSF.native = 1;  % Output native CSF volume
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.GM.warped = 0;   % Output normalized gray matter volume (in MNI space)
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.WM.warped = 0;   % Output normalized white matter volume (in MNI space)
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.CSF.warped = 0;  % Output normalized CSF volume (in MNI space)
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.GM.mod = 0;      % Output modulated gray matter volume (useful for VBM)
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.WM.mod = 0;      % Output modulated white matter volume
    matlabbatch{1}.spm.tools.cat.estwrite.output.warps = [1 1];   % Save forward and inverse deformation fields

    % Run the CAT12 segmentation
  %  spm('defaults', 'FMRI');
  %  spm_jobman('initcfg');
    spm_jobman('run', matlabbatch);

Any thoughts on how to tackle any of these three issues (or links to similar issues/documentation/FAQ) would be greatly appreciated!

It would help (us and you) if you simplified the problem and tested your MATLAB code with specific inputs in isolation, within the MATLAB IDE so you can add breakpoints, debug, and see full error traces. That would likely address point 1. where your code isn't behaving how you expect. For 2. Presumably VI is within spm_jobman but we can't see that here, the previous point would help in debugging this too. By the time we're at 3. this question is too broad, again we can't debug it here, I'd advise you run one of the problematic inputs within the MATLAB IDE and debug
